# What does this function do?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I found this piece of code on a website,
and I want to know what the function is and does.
I know PHP, HTML, CSS and JavaScript,
but I haven't learned JQUERY and AJAX yet. I especially need to know the routine they follow to put stuff in the colors array, it is random, or does it have a pattern:

`$('#onehour_next').css('backgroundColor', colors[(hours == 23 ? 0 : hours+1)]);`

```
function doStuff()
        {       
            current = new Date();
            hours = current.getHours();
            minutes = 59 - current.getMinutes();
            seconds = 59 - current.getSeconds();

            onehour.innerHTML = prettyTime(0, minutes, seconds);

            if (colors.length === 0 || current.getSeconds() === 0)
                init();

            $('#onehour').css('backgroundColor', colors[hours]);
            $('#onehour_next').css('backgroundColor', colors[(hours == 23 ? 0 : hours+1)]);

            setTimeout(doStuff, 1000);
        }
```

Comment: The `colors` array looks like it is created somewhere outside of this function and it is just being used here. Nothing gets appended/prepended to the `colors` array in this function.

Comment: `"but I haven't learned JQUERY and AJAX"` - There's minimal jQuery here, and no AJAX.  `"I especially need to know the routine they follow to put stuff in the colors array"` - This code doesn't put anything into `colors`.  That variable is defined/populated somewhere else.  What exactly are you asking about this code?  And when you debug this code, where does it behave differently than what you expect?

Comment: Do you guys need to see the whole code?

Comment: We need to know exactly what you're asking and the code related to that question. Before updating your answer, please have a look at this resource: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: But if you don't understand jQuery and you're working with jQuery, my suggestion would be to go learn jQuery. http://api.jquery.com/

Comment: @GoudenEnderoog have you asked the script author for information???

Answer (score 1):

The code is setting a different colour for each hour of the day.

The array `colors` isn't defined in this bit of code, but presumably it contains 24 different colours in a list.  The first colour in the list will be used from 11pm until 11:59, then at midnight the 2nd colour gets used and so on up until the 24th colour is used between 10pm and 10:59.

---

To explain how the code works, you need to look at each small segment.

- `hours == 23` is asking "is the hour of the day currently 23?  (ie 11pm)"
- `0` is just the number zero
- `hour + 1` is one higher than the current hour of the day.
- `question ? answer1 : answer2` basically says "if the question is true, then use answer1.  If it is false, use answer2"
- So `(hours == 23 ? 0 : hours+1)` essentially means "round the current time up to the next hour of the day" and will be a value between 0 and 23
- The `colors[n]` means "find the nth value in list colors".  Note that 0 is the 1st item, 1 is the 2nd and so on.
- `$('#onehour_next')` looks for the HTML element with id `onehour_next`
- `.css` sets the CSS of that element based on the next two values
- `'backgroundColor'` means it is setting the colour of the background of that element
- So the value we got from `colors[(hours == 23 ? 0 : hours+1)]` will be set as the background colour of element `onehour_next`